# UICalendar calendarView.reloadDecorations got error

Tags: swift5

I followed the "Display decorations for specific dates" in Apples UICalendar documentation . https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicalendarview

Please give me your advices.

The following is my code.

```
func reloardCalendarDecorations(){
        var dateComponents : [DateComponents] = []
        for event in appdelegate.eventsByMonth{
            var dateS :String = event["start"] as! String
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm"
            let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateS)
            print("date ",date!)
            let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
            let timeZone = TimeZone.current
            /// convert to dateComponents from date
            let components = calendar.dateComponents(in: timeZone, from: date!)
            print("components",components)
            dateComponents.append(components)
        }
        calendarView.reloadDecorations(forDateComponents: dateComponents, animated: true)
        /// got error
        /// Value of type '(UICalendarView, DateComponents) -> UICalendarView.Decoration?' has no member 'reloadDecorations'
    }
```

[image]

Please advise me how to use reloadDecorations.

Thank you.

Comment: Where is `calendarView` declared?

Comment: I made a careless mistake. calnderview was not declared properly as you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. please forget my silly question.